# I need help with LyX math environments. They keep changing typeface after reopening the app

Tags: math-mode, lyx

I have recently started using LyX. I am having some issues that none of my classmates nor my instructors could help me with.
Essentially whenever I close the application I and I reopen my document (only got to make 1 in LyX so far) the math environment shows up differently.
Example: The left picture is an example of how it looks when I open the document. The right picture shows how I want it to show up in the middle.

The lambda symbol shows up wrong, any idea on how to fix this?
Changing the font doesn't help.

[image: first image]
[image: second image]

Comment: Seems you are running into instant preview issues. Is the output PDF always correct? To make sure it is an instant preview issue, can you go to Tools > Preferences > Display and change "Instant preview" to "Off". Does everything display correctly now?

Comment: This helped. Thank you! You're a life saver!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short answer: turn off LyX's instant preview by going to Tools > Preferences > Display and change "Instant preview" to "Off".

Long answer: instant preview is a feature in LyX that allows you to view math as it would be shown in the final PDF output. It is a complicated feature and as such problems occur. Many of these problems have been fixed in LyX's upcoming 2.2.0 release. If you are interested, you may test the latest pre-release (currently beta2) by downloading the installers from [here](ftp://ftp.lyx.org/pub/lyx/devel/lyx-2.2/2.2.0-latest).

Advice: although it is nice to have the output as it would be displayed in the PDF, there are advantages to turning Instant Preview off, even if it is working. For example, using LyX's built-in math display, when you click in the middle of an equation, LyX will place the cursor exactly where you clicked. Using Instant Preview, you are essentially clicking on a picture so LyX does not know where to place your cursor (this could in theory be improved but would be quite difficult to do).

Comment: FWIW to any interested (like @Emil, our OP), I have been running 2.2.0beta on OSX because of the Retina support. It has been very well-behaved for me, anyway.

Comment: @Davïd that's great to hear! Let us know if you have any feedback on it at the lyx-devel mailing list.

Comment: Any info on how to turn off the "instant preview" on the LyX v2.2.2 release?  (this version does not have "preferences" show up under "Tools".) Restarting LyX seems to temporarily fix the above issue for me..

Comment: @Seb there are no preferences? Are you by chance on Mac? If so, maybe look under the "LyX" menu. There must be preferences in some menu entry or you have a broken installation.

Comment: The instant preview is showing pictures of other equations. Is there a way to "reset" the thumbnails, so that they are generated again?

Comment: @becko you could try zooming out/in.  I think that regenerates them. Otherwise, please post a bug report at https://www.lyx.org/trac . We would like to fix the root issue if you can provide a minimal example .lyx file.

Comment: @scottkosty So far it happens randomly. I have not been able to generate a minimal example that reproduces the issue consistenlty.

Comment: @becko dang, that is difficult to fix then. Thank you for trying though! Hopefully LyX version 2.3.0 (the release candidate will be out in a couple of weeks) will magically solve the problem, since there have been some instant-preview-related improvements.